# Views pager - start paging from 1

Tags: 7, views, paging

Views pager starts with 0 (URL GET argument "page" has value 0 for first page). Is it possible to set the pager, so it will start with 1?

I think it is more user friendly.

(if pager is starting with 0, and if the user click on page "3" there is page=2 in the URL)

thanks for help
Tomas

Comment: I'm afraid not without hacking views. But that's just my guess, not answer. Anyway you could probably add alias `/3` to `page=2` - as far as I remember pager understands aliases, if you are not using it with AJAX that is.

Comment: [Clean Pagination](https://drupal.org/project/cleanpager) might be a good starting point. Don't forget that the vast majority of users couldn't care less what the URL is, and will never even look at it - your time might be better spent on other things, as this probably won't be a quick fix

Comment: @Clive seems this module manages aliases the way I wrote in my previous comment... Should be way easier to modify it and add configurable offset, than to write it on my own. Or OP own. From scratch, anyway. Good to know someone put foundations already.