# Start page count from 1 with views pager

Tags: views, 8, paging

Is there a way to start the page count from 1 instead of 0 using views pager? Maybe using aliases or some module?

By default, the first page is displayed with the URL parameter `?page=0`, the second page with `?page=1` and so on. The pagination works good, but in my opinion it would be more coherent having the page one for the url with the parameter `?page=1`, the page 2 with `?page=2`, etc.

I found a similar question here, but it's about Drupal 7 and I'm on Drupal 8:
[Views pager - start paging from 1](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/108681/views-pager-start-paging-from-1)

Another discussion here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1818040, but without a solution.

Answer (score 1):

To change it just on the UI, you can adapt the number in [template_preprocess_pager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21pager.inc/function/template_preprocess_pager/8.2.x) in your theme's .theme file.

Something like:

```
function template_preprocess_pager(&$variables) {
  foreach ($variables['items']['pages'] as $key => $value) {
    $variables['items']['pages'][$key]['text'] = $key +1;
  }
}
```

To change the query params, you could use hook_url_inbound_alter and hook_url_outbound_alter to manipulate the queryparams, but this was D7.
In D8 you would need to go in this direction to manipulate them: [How do I implement the equivalent of hook_url_inbound_alter()?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/190232/how-do-i-implement-the-equivalent-of-hook-url-inbound-alter)

Comment: Thank you. In the html (returned by the pager template) I already have right page numbers, starting from 1. It is *"wrong"* in the URL: if I click on the link for the page 1 the URL parameter is `page=0`. Did the preprocess function fix the URL parameter also?

Comment: I edited the question to better explain my problem.

Comment: NO - the url will stay the same, this is only UI (display) correction ;) I made an update about manipulating the queryparam.

Comment: Thanks. I will make a try manipulating query parameters.